# Why can an object be cast to an array, but cannot be passed as an array argument in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, casting

If i have an array represented in an ArrayObject like this:

```php
$arrObj = new ArrayObject([
   'foo' => 1,
   'bar' => 2,
]);
```

Then I can comfortably cast it:

```php
print_r((array)$array);

// output is as expected
```

But I cannot pass it as an argument that's typed as an array:

```php
function castTest(array $array)
{
}

castTest($arrObj);

// TypeError: castTest(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, ArrayObject given
```

Is this intentional? Desirable? Are there any exceptions in PHP that CAN auto-cast objects to arrays?

It works with string objects, for example, with a __toString implemented:

```php
class Str
{
   private string $string;
   public function __construct(string $string)
   {
      $this->string = $string;
   }

   public function __toString()
   {
      return $this->string;
   }
}

function castTest(string $string)
{
   echo $string;
}

$str = new Str('hello, world');
castTest($str); // outputs: hello, world
```

Comment: I believe this is intentional. Any object can be cast as array, and this might disclose private/protected members. So autocasting might (and eventually will) bring unwanted results. You still can cast the object manually if you think you know what you'r doing. Compared to string auto-casting - the last is not fully auto, you still need to implement the `__toString`, so PHP believes the target function will get the correct data. Since there's no magical `__toArray` (and neither `__toInt`, `__toCallable`, etc), PHP cannot be sure that auto-casting will make everything correct. So its prohibited.

Comment: `castTest((array)$arrObj);` should work just fine. When you do `(array)$arrObj`, it doesn't change  `$arrObj` in place. For that you would need to assign it again as `$arrObj = (array)$arrObj`

Comment: Have a look at [The ArrayAccess interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), it allows you to access objects as arrays.

Comment: One other important distinction is the difference between casting and type-checking. Casting is the process of creating a new value by converting the original. Type-checking is just making sure something matches the type criteria. The `string` requirement is fulfilled by the `__toString` magic method which PHP safelists through (and `Stringable` was added to be less “magic”). Because casting is potentially destructive, the caller needs to do if it wants to match a type signature. There’s also [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) which is its own thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is intentional. The ArrayObject may behave like an array but isn't actually an array. PHP enforces strict typing in function arguments. If an argument is defined as an array it only accepts arrays. The behaviour you observed with the `__toString` method is different because when an object is used in a string context the `__toString` method is automaticaly called by PHP if it is defined. However, this behavior does not apply to arrays or other non-string types.

You can convert an ArrayObject to an Array by using `getArrayCopy()`

```php
castTest($arrObj->getArrayCopy());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's a different type and argument type checks are strict. An array is an `array` type. An `ArrayObject` is and "object" type (though there is no `Object` type, it is still a [separate type of variable in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-system.php)). This is also because PHP does not have scalar objects. They are objects that represent scalar values behind the scenes. For instance, if you create a `string` variable, a language with scalar objects would instantiate a `String` object transparently. This has been suggested to PHP a few times in the past, but not likely to get added soon.

However, you can allow array objects to be passed along with arrays by altering the argument's type restriction. PHP 8 introduced [union types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-system.php#language.types.type-system.composite.union) using the pipe character. You can allow objects able to be accessed like arrays through by adding the [`ArrayAccess` interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php):

```php
$arrObj = new ArrayObject([
   'foo' => 1,
   'bar' => 2,
]);

function castTest(array|ArrayAccess $array)
{
}

castTest($arrObj); // No problem here
```

The `array|ArrayAccess` type restriction means "only allow variables of type `array` or of object type `ArrayAccess`".

If you are using an older version of PHP (7 or earlier), your two options are to cast the object to an array (remember that it will no longer be an object within the function, but a separate array entirely which may have implications depending on how the data is handled), or check for types within the function itself. Here are examples:

1. Cast object to an array (e.g. make a copy of the object's values into a new array):

```php
function castTest(array $array)
{
}

castTest((array) $arrObj); // No problem here... ?
castTest($arrObj->getArrayCopy()); // Same as above, just using a method instead of type casting.
```

2. Check for type within the function:

```php
function castTest($array)
{
    if(!is_array($array) && !($array instanceof ArrayAccess)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Array or ArrayAccess object type expected, ' .
            (is_object($array) ?
                ('object of type ' . get_class($array)) :
                get_type($array)) . ' provided.'
        );
    }
}

castTest($arrObj); // If something other than an array or object with `ArrayAccess` is passed to the function, an exception is thrown.
```